# how i activate my account on my ledger wallet

Tags: transactions

how I can activate my stellar account. I try to send it to my leder wallet. not working. messeag Pop up . not activate

thanks for your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How are you trying to send XLM to your ledger? You need to use the createAccount operation, most wallet UI like lobstr or even CEX will do it automatically but if you do that manually with the laboratory you need to use the correct operation.